# Selenium test case running locally but not on azure pipeline using chrome driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My selenium testcases running locally in visual studio but when I check in the code on Azure build pipeline, its failing to locate the first element itself. Getting No such element exception.

Below is the CSProject nuget packages and dependencies I have added:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      <PublishChromeDriver>True</PublishChromeDriver>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExtentReports" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExtentReports.Core" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.9.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" Version="15.0.4795.1001" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" Version="3.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="108.0.5359.7100" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver" Version="107.0.1418.42" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

ChromeDriver runs successfully with the below error snippet.

```
<UnitTestResult executionId="00ad0f0d-8aea-41d7-8981-13961152aed9" testId="76a081c3-ed49-d739-5a18-7669ad294fce" testName="CreateSustainingProjectAndApproveGateDecision(&quot;Engineering Services&quot;)" computerName="compName" duration="00:00:20.4944700" startTime="2022-12-27T01:28:02.1595758-06:00" endTime="2022-12-27T01:28:22.6539741-06:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Failed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="00ad0f0d-8aea-41d7-8981-13961152aed9">
      <Output>
        <ErrorInfo>
          <Message>OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@id,'create')]"}&#xD;
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)&#xD;
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
          <StackTrace>   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)&#xD;
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)&#xD;
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)&#xD;
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__11_0(ISearchContext context)&#xD;
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)&#xD;
   `at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.FindElement(By by)&#xD;
   at PC.SeleniumUI.Tests.Start_Browser() in E:\AdosBuilds\ADOS-Agent1\1\s\UnitTests.cs:line 56&#xD;--TearDown&#xD;`
```

If anyone has ever faced this issue on Azure server, can guide me?

I have tried the options like

1. waiting for a 25 seconds delay, adding await delay instaed of Thread.sleep
2. Adding the below options

   ```
   var options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddArguments("--headless"); //for headless mode
   options.AddArguments("--window-size=800,600");//The invisible browser window is only 800x600 in size
   options.AddArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
   options.AddArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
   options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
   options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
   options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
   options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
   options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features='BlockCredentialedSubresources'");
   options.AddArguments("--whitelisted-ips='10.5.243.86'");
   ```
3. Pass the authentication parameters
4. using CssSelector instead of Xpath

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver is being used when running the test in the Azure pipeline? I bet the versions do not match.